# Passing aliases and fields into pig macros

Tags: macros, apache-pig

I am trying to pass aliases and fields in them to a pig macro:

```
define mymac (a1, f, a2) returns void {
  foreach (join $a1 on $f, $a2 on field) generate
    $a1::$f as $f, $a2::field as field;
};
```

I get an error

```
Unexpected character '$'
```

on the second `$` in `$a1::$f` when I call the macro as

```
mymac(x,foo,y);
```

I also tried

```
define mymac (a1, f, af, a2) returns void {
  foreach (join $a1 on $f, $a2 on field) generate
    $af as $f, $a2::field as field;
};
mymac(x,foo,x::foo,y);
```

and got even more cryptic error

```
org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Pig script failed to parse: at expanding macro
```

So, what do I do? How do I combine alias with a field in a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put field names in `''` when calling the macro, for example `mymac(x,'foo','x::foo',y);`. I have tested the 2nd approach you mentioned and it works.